# OOP Javascript Callback

Tags: javascript, oop, callback, asynccallback

I've really been having trouble grasping this concept and thought if I saw it on a little bit of my own code it might click. I'd really like to take advantage of callback functions while still keeping an object oriented approach. Thank you for any help you can offer!

```
//adds functionality to buttons
    addClickEvent(newDataCollect,function() {addClickEvent(dataSubmitBtn, function(){testAjax(dataForm.elements);});

        function addClickEvent(elem,click,addtl) {
            var nwClickEvent = new elemEvents(elem,click,addtl);
            nwClickEvent.onClick();
      }

      //add click event object & properties
      function elemEvents(elem,click,addtl) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.click = click;
        this.addtl = addtl;
      }

      //add click event object method
      elemEvents.prototype = {
        onClick: function() {this.elem.onclick = this.click;}
      }
```

Comment: sorry but what's your problem?

Comment: I'd like to utilize a callback function, but I'm not sure how. Perhaps I'm already doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would say you are using a callback already:

```
//add click event object & properties (constructors should be PascalCase)
function ElemEvents(elem,click,addtl) {
    this.elem = elem;
    // `click` should be a function, and as such, a callback that is called when the element is clicked
    this.elem.onclick = click;
    this.addtl = addtl;
}

// later:
var e = new ElemEvents(
    // the `elem`
    document.getElementById("id"),

    // this is the callback.
    function (event) {
        console.log("hi from event: " + event);
    },
    // the `addtl`.
    "");
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything clicked after reading this and the implementation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind here is that callbacks are not necessarily asynchronous. In this particular case, you are defining an `onClick` handler which will run once the user clicks on something, at some point in the future. This is async - but consider the following:

```
function log(/* .. */){ // can be any arguments, we're just .apply'ing log with arguments
  console.log.apply(console, arguments)
}

function logThen(done /* .. */) { // takes a callback as first argument, then vals to log
  var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 1); // calls splice on the arguments, removing the CB, and returning whatever you had left
  console.log.apply(console, args);
  if (done && typeof done === 'function'){
    done();
  }
}

log(1);
log(2);
log(3);
logThen(alert, 4);
log(5);
log(6);
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
4  // shows an alert, then continues with.. 
5
6
```

This is all synchronous code - there is nothing that is pushed onto the next call stack, so it executes everything, including your callback (in this case `alert`) synchronously.

Just a little heads up!